# Convert LIRC config file to Arduino IR remote command

Tags: esp8266, ir, remote-control, convert

I have a [LED 24 button remote](http://is.alicdn.com/img/pb/557/412/430/430412557_545.jpg) with a few broken buttons and I want to simulate all the buttons with an esp8266 using an [IR remote library](https://github.com/markszabo/IRremoteESP8266).

I would like to know if someone can help me translate the LIRC config file with all the functional buttons to an ESP lib command.
I have 2 lircd.conf files of the same remote (everything worked on a raspberry) and I'm using the same circuit on an ESP8266 (wemos d1 mini pin D5 and D6).

lircd.conf 1

```
begin remote

  name  lumina
  bits           16
  flags SPACE_ENC|CONST_LENGTH
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  header       8860  4530
  one           508  1724
  zero          508   607
  ptrail        508
  repeat       8863  2301
  pre_data_bits   16
  pre_data       0xFF
  gap          107224
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0

      begin codes
          PWR_ON                   0xB04F
          PWR_OFF                  0xF807
          LI_LOW                   0xB847
          LI_HI                    0x906F
          R                        0x9867
          G                        0xD827
          B                        0x8877
          W                        0xA857
          R1                       0xE817
          R2                       0x02FD
          B4                       0xF00F
          G1                       0x48B7
          B1                       0x6897
          FLASH                    0xB24D
          STROBE                   0x00FF
          FADE                     0x58A7
          SMOOTH                   0x30CF
          G2                       0x32CD
          R3                       0x50AF
          R4                       0x38C7
          G3                       0x7887
          G4                       0x28D7
          B2                       0x20DF
          B3                       0x708F
      end codes

end remote
```

lircd.conf 2

```
begin remote

  name  lumina
  bits           16
  flags SPACE_ENC|CONST_LENGTH
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  header       8861  4525
  one           515  1718
  zero          515   600
  ptrail        516
  repeat       8865  2291
  pre_data_bits   16
  pre_data       0xFF
  gap          107235
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0

      begin codes
          B1                       0x6897
          PWR_ON                   0xB04F
          PWR_OFF                  0xF807
          LI_LOW                   0xB847
          LI_HI                    0x906F
          R                        0x9867
          G                        0xD827
          B                        0x8877
          W                        0xA857
          R1                       0x9867
      end codes

end remote
```

Output from a few buttons read from the esp using the IRremoteESP8266 library .

```
F0C41643
4039382595
Unknown encoding: F0C41643 (32 bits)
Raw (68): 8850 -4550 550 -650 550 -650 550 -650 500 -650 550 -600 550 -650 550 -650 550 -600 550 -1750 550 -1750 500 -1750 500 -1750 550 -1750 500 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 500 -1750 500 -650 500 -1750 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -650 500 -650 550 -650 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 500 -600 550 -1750 500 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 500 
------------------


A3C8EDDB
2747854299
Unknown encoding: A3C8EDDB (32 bits)
Raw (68): 8900 -4550 550 -650 550 -600 550 -650 550 -650 550 -600 550 -650 550 -600 550 -600 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -600 550 -600 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 
------------------


86B0E697
2259740311
Unknown encoding: 86B0E697 (32 bits)
Raw (68): 8900 -4550 550 -600 550 -650 550 -650 550 -600 550 -600 550 -650 550 -600 550 -600 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -600 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -600 550 -600 550 -650 550 -650 550 -600 550 -1750 550 -600 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 
------------------


A3C8EDDB
2747854299
Unknown encoding: A3C8EDDB (32 bits)
Raw (68): 8900 -4550 550 -650 550 -600 550 -650 550 -600 550 -650 500 -650 550 -600 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -1750 500 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 550 -600 550 -650 500 -650 550 -1750 550 -650 500 -1750 550 -650 550 -1750 550 -1750 550 -1750 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like is just plain NEC IR protocol. So use something like `irsend.sendNEC(0xB04F, 16)` for POWER_ON.

Comment: did with a few of those values, tried 16 and 32 for the second value